# maven-assembly-plugin loops over each module without being told to do so

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am just trying to copy some files into some directories, and using this plugin since I am told that it is convenient. However, whenever I try to do `mvn install`, the plugin somehow tries to loop over every module in my `pom.xml` (I never asked it to do this kind of thing) and tries to do some operation, then gives the error of :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (make-install-assembly) on project untoldProject Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive install: You must set at least one file.
```

I want this plugin to operate on only certain modules (and folders which are not modules) which I already specify in the path, in the assembly file of mine. So I don't know why is the plugin tries to do this operation for every module.

Here is my **`pom.xml`** where I use the plugin:

```
<!-- This plugin is used to copy the necessary files to project.release/install folder -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-install-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
              <inherited>true</inherited>
              <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                  <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <attach>true</attach>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here is my **`asssembly.xml`** where I specify what I want to copy:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>install</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>project.release/template</directory>
            <outputDirectory>project.release/install</outputDirectory>
            <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
            <includes>
                <include>run.all.sh</include>
                <include>kill.all.sh</include>
                <include>packlogs.sh</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>config.properties</exclude>
                <exclude>run.all.ant</exclude>
                <exclude>run.ant</exclude>
                <exclude>packlogs.sh</exclude>
                <exclude>install.sh</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Given this, why does the plugin try to do this operation for every module? I just want it to happen for one module, called project.release, and that's it. I put both of my `pom.xml` and `assembly.xml` to the parent directory, for your information.

**Update:** For those who would like to see my project hiearchy, here is my master `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>runtime_project</groupId>
   <artifactId>runtime_project.master</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <properties>
      <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
   </properties>
   <modules>
      <module>project.messages</module>
      <module>project.base</module>
      <module>project.logging</module>
      <module>project.mission.launch</module>
      <module>project.mission.detach</module>
      <module>project.settingsStore</module>
   </modules>
   <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>${jdk.version}</source>
               <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>  

        <!-- This plugin is used to delete the contents of the project.release/install folder-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
           </executions>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                <filesets>
                  <fileset>
                    <directory>project.release/install</directory>
                    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                    <includes>
                      <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                  </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
        <!-- This plugin is used to copy the necessary files to project.release/install folder -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-install-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
              <inherited>true</inherited>
              <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                  <descriptor>deploy.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <attach>true</attach>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Comment: @Ulrich Check again please, would this be enough or you need more?

Comment: OK. **First:** It's in the nature of a maven multi module project that the plugins that you define within `<plugins>` of the root POM are executed over all modules. **Second:** You speak of a module named `project.release`, but this isn't included in your modules list.

Comment: For the **first point**: How can make this getting executed **only** for some specific modules, not all? **Second:** It's just a folder (sorry it is not a module with `pom.xml`) that I want to copy the files from. Does it have to be a module with `pom.xml`?

Comment: let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given this, why does the plugin try to do this operation for every
>   module?

Because this is the nature of multi module project.

> I just want it to happen for one module, called project.release, and
>   that's it. I put both of my pom.xml and assembly.xml to the parent
>   directory, for your information.

I give some hints, not a complete solution.

1. create an additional module called `project.release`. Add it to the `<modules>` element in the root POM. The order doesn`t matter
2. move the plugin-entry for the maven-assembly-plugin from the root POM to the POM of `project.release`
3. In the POM of `project.release`, add dependencies to other modules as necessary.
4. In the folder of `project.release`, place the assembly descriptor in `src/main/assembly` . The directory entries within your descriptor should be relative to the module root of `project.release`

Comment: So in order for this plugin to operate, the operation folder should be the root folder of a module, is that so? The consensus is then that we cannot use it to conduct simple folder/file operations from the master POM.

Comment: @Schütze correct. If german language isn't a problem, see Martin Spiller, "Maven 3 - Konfigurationsmanagement mit Java"

Comment: By the way, I just noticed but do you know why does it copy the files into the `target` folder, leaving a message like `[INFO] Copying files to ~/workspace_runtime_project/project.release/target/project.release-1.0.0


[WARNING] Assembly file: ~/workspace_runtime_project/project.release/target/project.release-1.0.0 is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.`